# Matching backticks/accute accents for ES6 template literals should appear immediately in VS Code

Tags: ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, template-literals

When I enter an apostrophe / single quote in VS Code, VS Code will automatically add a second one and put the cursor in between of the two. I want the same behaviour when I enter the acute accent `. By default, it will not show anything at first in order to allow creating special characters such as è. That might be useful in other applications, but definitely not needed in VS Code. Is there a way to fix that?

It's mostly an aesthetics thing, but I find it distracting when writing code.

Comment: What kind of file is that not working for you?  Because it works for me in .js files.  VSCode 1.23.1.